# Boolean and bad topology

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am working on a scene with differents buildings, pierced with arch-shaped windows.
Given the number of windows, using the boolean modifier would allow me to do it quickly. But since once applied, it generates a bad topology, it becomes difficult to edit the mesh afterwards.

Is there a way to use the Boolean modifier while preserving the topology?

Comment: *"Is there a way to use the Boolean modifier while preserving the topology?"* - no, because the only role of the boolean is to change the topology. However, understanding what makes a topology *"good"* or *"bad"* will help with using booleans. For example, take a look at a trick in this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249544/60486) of mine, that creates a quad buffer of quads co-planar with the resulting ngon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, unless you bulldoze everything with an automatic remesh after applying the booleans, the best way is to have a good topology from the start and think it ahead.
So basically, prepare the topology for the booleans you need. Once you are happy with the shapes of your boolean, add the geometry they will need.

Booleans will add supporting edges whenever it is needed, if YOU provide the support the way YOU want, you will have a better topology at the end. Typically in your example, adding vertical loops at the top and bottom of your windows and also horizontal ones at the apex of the arches will probably help. I would also add support between the shapes to even out the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

before bollen add loop cut where new elements should be.
And if you want nicer mesh after all use blender new remesh tool from sculpt tools its great!

Comment: Adding the loop cuts doesn't really help with the topology. I still have trouble editing the mesh afterwards. As for the tool mentioned, which one is it exactly? Because on my version of Blender (2.82), I don't see anything like that.

Comment: also, did you do loop cut before collapsing bollen? it should be before

Answer (score 0):

Go to sculpting remesh is on top or right bar depending on tool aligment. remember to use adaptation this one is useful where you have lot of flats check out quads too[image]