# Trying to model a squat rack

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I have been trying to model a squat rack based off of this photo here. [image]

As you can see, the object contains a lot of holes. The best method I know for creating holes in an object (Boolean) really screw up the mesh which would make shading almost impossible when it comes time to do the shading. I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to approach this project more effeciently. Currently im working on one of the 4 stands and am stuck trying to wrap my head around how I would go about proceeding to create all these holes while still allowing for shading to be done. Any advice would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a cube and subdivide with 3 cuts.

[image]

Delete all top and bottom vertices to make your hollow square for the base shape.

[image]

Add some more loops at the edges to support subdivision later. (New loops highlighted)

[image]

Now, for each side, delete the center vert and *Scale* the surrounding 4 corner verts closer to the center with <kbd>S</kbd> until you get something close to an octagon.

[image]

Now you should be able to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *Select* one of the edges of that octagon to select the whole thing, and *Extrude* <kbd>E</kbd> and immediately *Scale* <kbd>S</kbd> to create a slightly smaller supporting loop for the octagon shape.  Do this for each side also and you should end up with this.

[image]

These three modifiers set up like this should allow you to build as much of this as you want, quickly.

[image]

And then of course duplicating it and editing the base shape you should be able to achieve the different spacings.

Here's the result.

[image]

Comment: But in general when you are doing things multiple times repeatedly or want a lot of flexibility with low commitment, look to modifiers.  There are other UI tweaks and commands that I used here to avoid doing things multiple times for each side, but the post was already long enough.

Answer (score 4):

As @Allen Simpson has mentioned, you might look to modifiers to do the job. Staring with a single-skin bar, with enough subdivision to accommodate the various hole-frequencies, this stack does a reasonable job of turning a vertex group 'Holes' into holes.  (Top to Bottom):

1. *Bevel*. Vertices, Absolute,2 segments, limit: the 'Holes' vertex group
2. *Mask*. The 'Holes' group, inverted, threshold tweaked to the desired outcome.
3. *Smooth*. 1 repeat, amount by eye, to a circle.
4. *Solidify*. Outwards, to the desired thickness.
5. *Bevel*. Edges, by angle, to crisp up the *Solidify* rim and hold..
6. *Subdivision Surface*.. minimum necessary.

[image]

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd>, 'Select Next Active' will help you select sequences of vertices quickly)

The resulting topo is passable, if you can afford it, especially with that Hammerite paint-finish...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not that it isn't annoyingly slow, but if you make a `cutter` cylinder :

[image]

And then duplicate it to create a `filler` cylinder with ngons removed and inner circles bridged:

[image]

Then if you make sure the `filler` has its ends co-planar with the boolean base, and the `cutter` is slightly extended, you can first boolean > difference `cutter` than boolean > union `filler` for a "good" topology:

[image]

By "good" I mean that the ngons have a buffer of quads co-planar with them, though that's only half true, as I didn't add loop cuts near the original cuboid edges, so the buffer here is only on the side of holes. Also keep in mind for subdivision surface it's ideal to have a buffer of two levels of quads.